# Create about 100 Radiobuttons with "Array" or "For"

Tags: android, radio-button, declare

Maybe a simple question: my app uses 100 radiobuttons (and 50 EditTexts). I tried to do declare the radiobuttons this way:

`RadioButton[] rdBtn = new RadioButton[100];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        final RadioButton rdbtn[i];
    }`

but thats not the right way i see. At the end i want to have that

`final RadioButton rdBtn1, rdBtn2, rdBtn3, rdBtn4, rdBtn5, rdBtn6, rdBtn7, rdBtn8, rdBtn9, rdBtn10, ..., ..., rdBtn99, rdBtn100 ;`

solved in an shorter way

Comment: Your radiobuttons are dynamic right?

Comment: no. the 100 buttons are fix. it are always 100 radiobuttons at the start of the app. they do not get more or less or change anyway. i just do not want to type the 100 rdBtn declare. Cause this are 100 lines of code. i thought i can do it in maybe 10 lines of code. therefore the question with that array

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a very bad variant of coding.
But anyway try to use a reflections.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           RadioButton rdbtn[i] = (RadioButton ) findViewById(R.id.class.getField("radiobutton" + Integer.toString(i)).getInt(null));
```